# 3 routers, 1 network (or subnet)

Tags: networking, home-networking, home-server

I want to have a server that will be accessible in any WiFi network in my home.
I've already set up the server but it's only accessible from 1 subnet.

Here is my configuration:

```
                    [repeater]-----[laptop]
                       |
     ---------------[router]-----[TV]
     |                  |
---[router]          [router]----------[laptop]
     |                     |
     ---------------[PC]   ---------------[server]
```

Comment: Place all the routers on the same subnet (i.e. `192.168.10.0/26` or `/24`, `/25`), using one of them as the DHCP server and configuring the rest as DHCP clients.  You could also place each router on consecutive subnets (i.e. Router1: `192.168.10.0/26`, Router2: `192.168.10.64/26`, Router3: `192.168.10.128/26`, etc.)

Comment: I think I tried to do something like that but the internet connection stopped working. How do I place them on the same subnet?

Comment: If the router's don't offer the ability to bridge the WAN port with the LAN ports, you'd daisy chain each router by connecting a CAT6 cable from one router's LAN port to the other's LAN port, or by connecting each router's LAN port to the master router's LAN ports.  If bridging via WiFi, it's a bit more complex and you'll want to follow a wiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you connect the wireless routers as follows:

1. LAN port on Wireless router to LAN port on the main network.
2. Each wireless router to have a Static IP address on the main network. Edit the Router settings to do this.
3. Turn DHCP OFF on each wireless router.
4. Restart (not Reset) each wireless router to ensure it works.

Test one, then add the next and test and then add the third and test.

I have done this many times.

Comment: Will internet connection on the second router still work? I think it only works when I connect the LAN cable from the first router to WAN port on the second one.

Comment: If you connect as I suggest, yes. All will work on the network and for the Internet

Comment: @adazem009 Do not use the WAN ports on any, except for the master router running the DHCP server, which is the only one that should have it's WAN port in use connecting it to the modem. The reason why you lose the internet after connecting to the second router's WAN port is you're double NAT'd _(all traffic downstream is now passing through the second router's stateful firewall)_... this is not what you want or need.  Only scenarios in which you'd want to use the downstream routers' WAN ports is for a second firewall (it will be double NAT'd) or if able to bridge the WAN port w/ the LAN ports

Comment: Ok I don't have time to do it now so I tried it on the 3rd router. I connected the WAN cable to the LAN port, disabled DHCP server and internet works! Thanks for your help, I'll set it up when I have time :)

Comment: If you have any issues just post back here

Comment: Ok so I tried to set it up. Every device except an old Windows XP laptop was able to connect. It seems Windows XP doesn't like when the WAN cable is in the LAN port...

Comment: XP is getting too old to correct anything. You can try updating the LAN driver via Device Manager.